# What should I do to prevent the app from crashing while using MapView with Google Maps?

Tags: react-native, build, expo, crash, apk

Hi I'm studying React Native and using expo go.

I wanted to show map by MapView with Google Maps API.
And there were no errors when tested with the simulator.
However, error appeared after converting to apk file.
It just stop whenever I try to open a map page.

I'm searching all the docs, but I couldn't find a solution for my problem.

Below is my whole code of the page which has mapView in it.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Pressable } from 'react-native';

import { PROVIDER_GOOGLE, Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

import Header from '../components/fixed/Header';

import Colors from "../constants/Colors";
import { getSafeContentHeight } from '../constants/DeviceSize';
import deviceSize from "../constants/DeviceSize";

const deviceWidth = deviceSize.deviceWidth;
const deviceHeight = deviceSize.deviceHeight;

export default function MapPush({ navigation, route }) {

  const { myLocation } = route.params;

  const [safeContentHeight, safeContentHeightWithoutNav] = getSafeContentHeight();


  const [pressedMarkerInfo, setPressedMarkerInfo] = useState(null);

  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View style={{ width: deviceWidth, height: safeContentHeightWithoutNav, paddingTop: 50 }}>
      <Header title="홍대입구역 9번출구" isPush={true} navigation={navigation} />
      <MapView
        style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
        region={{
          latitude: 37.55604312175928,
          longitude: 126.92299623955266,
          latitudeDelta: 0.01827,
          longitudeDelta: 0.01198
        }}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: 37.55604312175928,
          longitude: 126.92299623955266,
          latitudeDelta: 0.01827,
          longitudeDelta: 0.01198
        }}
        minZoomLevel={12}
        maxZoomLevel={20}
        showsUserLocation={true}
        showsMyLocationButton={true}
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
      >
      <Marker
        coordinate={{
          latitude: 37.55604312175928,
          longitude: 126.92299623955266,
        }}
        pinColor="red"
        onPress={() => {
          setIsModalOpen(true)
        }}
      >
        <View style={[
          styles.markerContainer,
        ]}>
          <Text
            style={[
              styles.markerText,
            ]}
          >
            홍대입구역 9번출구
          </Text>
          
        </View>
        <View 
          style={[
            styles.markerTriangle,
          ]}
        />
      </Marker>
      </MapView>
    </View>
  )
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {},
  markerContainer: {
    position: 'relative',
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 7,
    borderRadius: 30,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: Colors.cool_gray2
  },
  markerText: {
    fontFamily: 'GothicA1-Bold',
    fontSize: deviceWidth / 400 * 16.5, 
    lineHeight: deviceWidth / 400 * 17.5, 
    color: Colors.cool_gray5
  },
  markerTriangle: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    // borderWidth: 8,
    borderColor: 'transparent',
    borderTopColor: Colors.cool_gray2,
    borderWidth: 13,
    marginTop: -1
  },
})
```

And I'll also put App.js, and other imported components in MapPush

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
// import LottieView from "lottie-react-native";
import { SafeAreaProvider, SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();



import PinUp from "./src/components/animations/PinUp";
// import LogIn from "./src/screens/LogIn";

import NavBar from './src/components/fixed/NavBar';

import Home from './src/screens/Home';
import PinDetail from './src/screens/PinDetail';
import MapPush from "./src/screens/MapView";

import Records from './src/screens/Records';

import FindPin from './src/screens/FindPin';
import MakePin from "./src/screens/MakePin";
import Search from './src/screens/Search';
import SearchMap from "./src/screens/SearchMap";
import MakePinSearch from "./src/screens/makePinSearch";
import Map from "./src/screens/Map";

import Invites from './src/screens/Invites';
import FriendRequest from './src/screens/FriendRequest';

import MyBoard from './src/screens/MyBoard';
import OthersBoard from './src/screens/OthersBoard';
import Settings from './src/screens/Settings';
import ProfileSetting from "./src/screens/ProfileSetting";

import Notice from './src/screens/Notice';

import KaKaoLogin from "./src/screens/KakaoLogin";



import { getLocationPermissionHandler } from "./src/expoSDK/expoLocation";

import Colors from './src/constants/Colors';
import deviceSize from "./src/constants/DeviceSize";
import LogIn from "./src/screens/LogIn";

const deviceWidth = deviceSize.deviceWidth;
const deviceHeight = deviceSize.deviceHeight;


export default function App() {

  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'GothicA1-Thin': require('./assets/fonts/GothicA1-Thin.ttf'),
    'GothicA1-ExtraLight': require('./assets/fonts/GothicA1-ExtraLight.ttf'),
    'GothicA1-Light': require('./assets/fonts/GothicA1-Light.ttf'),
    'GothicA1-Regular': require('./assets/fonts/GothicA1-Regular.ttf'),
    'GothicA1-Medium': require('./assets/fonts/GothicA1-Medium.ttf'),
    'GothicA1-SemiBold': require('./assets/fonts/GothicA1-SemiBold.ttf'),
    'GothicA1-Bold': require('./assets/fonts/GothicA1-Bold.ttf'),
    'GothicA1-ExtraBold': require('./assets/fonts/GothicA1-ExtraBold.ttf'),
    'GothicA1-Black': require('./assets/fonts/GothicA1-Black.ttf'),
  });


  // const animationRef = useRef<LottieView>(null);

  const [login, setLogin] = useState(false);

  const [locationPermissionStatus, setLocationPermissionStatus] = useState();

  const [isSplash, setIsSplash] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    // animationRef.current?.play(30, 120);

    getLocationPermissionHandler()
      .then(status => setLocationPermissionStatus(status))


    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsSplash(false)
      setLogin(true);
    }, 3 * 1000)
  }, []);


  if (fontsLoaded && locationPermissionStatus === 'granted') {


    function TabNav() {
      return (
        <Tab.Navigator
          screenOptions={() => ({ headerShown: false })}
          tabBar={props => <NavBar {...props} />}
        >
          <Tab.Screen name="참여중" component={Home} />
          <Tab.Screen name="참여내역" component={Records} />
          <Tab.Screen name="방찾기" component={FindPin}
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
            initialParams={{ locationPermissionStatus: locationPermissionStatus }}
          />
          <Tab.Screen name="알림" component={Invites} />
          <Tab.Screen name="내 보드" component={MyBoard}
            initialParams={{ smoke: '비흡연', drink: '금주중', img: null }}
          />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      )
    }


    return (
      <>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: Colors.cool_gray_minus_1 }}>
          <SafeAreaProvider>
            <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>

              {isSplash && <PinUp />}
              {login && <LogIn setLogin={setLogin} />}
              <NavigationContainer>

                {/* {login && <LogIn setLogin={setLogin} />} */}

                <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
                  <Stack.Screen name="TabNav" component={TabNav} />
                  <Stack.Screen name="공지" component={Notice} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                  <Stack.Screen name="검색" component={Search} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                  <Stack.Screen name="상대 보드" component={OthersBoard} options={{ headerShown: false }}
                    initialParams={{ isHost: null }}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen name="설정" component={Settings} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                  <Stack.Screen name="핀 상세" component={PinDetail} options={{ headerShown: false }}
                    initialParams={{ displayLeftDate: null, isIn: null, isOver: null }}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen name="친구 요청" component={FriendRequest} options={{ headerShown: false }}
                    initialParams={{ isList: null, isBlock: null }}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen name="핀 생성" component={MakePin} options={{ headerShown: false }}
                    initialParams={{ myLocation: null, selectedLocationInfo: null, selectedSchools: null, selectedFriends: null }}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen name="장소 검색" component={SearchMap} options={{ headerShown: false }}
                    initialParams={{ myLocation: null }}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen name="핀 생성 검색" component={MakePinSearch} options={{ headerShown: false }}
                    initialParams={{ isFriend: null, myLocation: null, selectedLocationInfo: null }}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen name="지도보기" component={MapPush} options={{ headerShown: false }}
                    initialParams={{ myLocation: null }}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen name="카카오로그인" component={KaKaoLogin} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                  <Stack.Screen name="프로필 설정" component={ProfileSetting} options={{ headerShown: false }}
                    initialParams={{ smoking: null, drinking: null, img: null }}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen name="방찾기 지도" component={Map}
                    initialParams={{ myLocation: null }}
                  />
                </Stack.Navigator>

              </NavigationContainer>
            </SafeAreaView>
          </SafeAreaProvider>
        </View>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

```js
import { Dimensions, Platform } from "react-native";
import { useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const deviceHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

const deviceSize = { deviceWidth, deviceHeight };

export default deviceSize;

export function getSafeContentHeight() {
  const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();
  
  const safeContentHeight = deviceHeight - (insets.top + insets.bottom + (Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 58 : 68));
  const safeContentHeightWithoutNav = deviceHeight - (insets.top + insets.bottom);

  return [safeContentHeight, safeContentHeightWithoutNav];
};
```

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, Pressable, StyleSheet, TextInput, Platform } from "react-native";
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';

import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

import Colors from "../../constants/Colors";
import deviceSize from "../../constants/DeviceSize"

const deviceWidth = deviceSize.deviceWidth;
const deviceHeight = deviceSize.deviceHeight;

export default function Header({
  title, 
  toggleMenu, selected, setSelected, 
  isSearch, inputText, setInputText, keywordSearchHttpHandler,
  isPush, navigation, ContaienrStyle,

  isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen,
  pressedMarkerInfo, setPressedMarkerInfo,
  searchRes, setSearchRes,
  isSchoolPage, selectedSchools,
  myLocation,
  selectedLocationInfo
}) {

  if (title && !toggleMenu) {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container, ContaienrStyle]}>
        {
          isPush ?
            <Pressable
              style={styles.titleBox}
              onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
            >
              <MaterialIcons name="arrow-back-ios" size={19} color={Colors.black} />
              <Text style={[styles.title]}>
                {title}
              </Text>
            </Pressable>
            :
            <Text style={styles.title}>
              {title}
            </Text>
        }
      </View>
    )
  } else if (!title && toggleMenu) {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container, ContaienrStyle]}>
        {
          isPush &&
          <Pressable onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
            <MaterialIcons name="arrow-back-ios" size={19} color={Colors.black} />
          </Pressable>
        }
        {
          toggleMenu.map((a, i) => {
            return (
              <Pressable
                style={styles.toggleMenuBox}
                onPress={() => setSelected(a)}
                key={i}
              >
                <Text style={[styles.toggleMenu, selected === a && { color: Colors.black }]}>{a}</Text>
              </Pressable>
            )
          })
        }
      </View>
    )
  } else if (isSearch) {
    return (
      <LinearGradient
        style={[styles.container, ContaienrStyle]}
        colors={[Colors.cool_gray02, Colors.cool_gray02_trans]}
      >
        {
          isPush &&
          <Pressable onPress={() => {
            if(isModalOpen) {
              if(pressedMarkerInfo) {
                setPressedMarkerInfo(null);
              } else if (searchRes){
                setSearchRes(null);
                setIsModalOpen(false)
              }
            } else {
              if (isSchoolPage) {
                console.log(selectedLocationInfo)
                navigation.navigate('핀 생성', {
                  myLocation: myLocation, 
                  selectedSchools: null, 
                  selectedLocationInfo: selectedLocationInfo
                })
              } else {
                navigation.goBack()
              }
            }
          }}>
            <MaterialIcons name="arrow-back-ios" size={19} color={Colors.cool_gray4} />
          </Pressable>
        }
        <View style={styles.textInputContainer}>
          <TextInput
            value={inputText}
            onChangeText={(text) => setInputText(text)}
            onSubmitEditing={() => keywordSearchHttpHandler()}
            placeholder="검색어를 입력하세요"
            style={styles.textInput}
          />
        </View>
      </LinearGradient>
    )
  }
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: deviceWidth,
    height: 50,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
    backgroundColor: Colors.cool_gray_minus_1,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    paddingBottom: 13,
    shadowColor: "black",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 1,
      height: 2
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.05,
    elevation: 1
  },

  titleBox: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center'
    // justifyContent: 
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 16.5,
    // lineHeight: 17.5,
    // fontFamily: 'GothicA1-Bold',
    fontWeight: 700,
    marginTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? null : - deviceWidth / 400 * 3
  },

  toggleMenuBox: {
    marginRight: 13
  },
  toggleMenu: {
    fontSize: 16.5,
    // lineHeight: 17,
    // fontFamily: 'GothicA1-Bold',
    fontWeight: 700,
    color: Colors.cool_gray3,
    marginTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? null : - deviceWidth / 400 * 3
  },

  textInputContainer: {
    width: deviceWidth * 0.85,
    height: 30,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: Colors.white_semiTrans,
    marginLeft: deviceWidth / 400 * 5,
    marginBottom: -5,
    borderRadius: 10
  },
  textInput: {
    width: deviceWidth * 0.8,
    height: 27,
    // backgroundColor: 'red',
    // fontFamily: 'GothicA1-SemiBold',
    fontSize: 15.5,
    // lineHeight: 16,

    // fontWeight: 600,
    paddingTop: 2,
    color: Colors.cool_gray5
  },
})
```

And my package.json file

```js
{
  "name": "pinup",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@jiggag/react-native-kakao-maps": "^0.0.10",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.7.3",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.4.2",
    "@react-native-seoul/kakao-login": "^5.3.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.6.0",
    "expo-camera": "~13.2.1",
    "expo-font": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.1.2",
    "expo-linking": "~4.0.1",
    "expo-location": "~15.1.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-kakao-maps-sdk": "^1.1.11",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-asset": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-maps": "1.3.2",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.9.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-webview": "11.26.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
}
```

What should I do to make my app not to crash and stop?

Comment: Hey, to investigate why it's crashing when using the apk file I recommend the following. 
1. Connect your phone or emulator to your computer (make sure it shows up when running `adb devices`)
2. Run `adb logcat`, that will show you all the logs of your device. Alternatively you can run `adb logcat | grep -e com.your.package.name` to filter the results more granularly.
3. In the logcat logs you should see an error, why the app crashed, you can also post that full log here for us to help investigate

Comment: Thank you so much. I was also looking for a way to check for errors.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding my api key properly in app.json under android.config.googleMaps.apiKey

```js
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.your.app",
      "NSAppTransportSecurity": {
        "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads": true,
        "NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent": true
      },
      "config": {
        "googleMapsApiKey": "YOUR API KEY"
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.your.app",
      "config": {
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey" : "YOUR API KEY"
        }
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.your.app",
      "NSAppTransportSecurity": {
        "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads": true,
        "NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent": true
      },
      "config": {
        "googleMapsApiKey": "YOUR API KEY"
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.your.app",
      "config": {
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey" : "YOUR API KEY"
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35822344)